# PHP Best Approach Storing Cloud File Sharing

Tags: php, cloud, storage

I am developing Cloud File Storage that can be accessed by specific users. 
What is the best way to store folders and files?

What I mean is either the folder created in Database or the folder create in the real folder in server.

These way must be considered to which one is fast and secure.

Answer (score 0):

All the methods has its own advantages and should be used based on your use case.

1) Storing in Database

2) Storing in real folder
or , may be 
3)  storing in AWS cloud storage like s3

Some of the pros / cons  revolve around

1. Size of the Individual file
2. How many files are you storing.
3. Concurrent users trying to download each file.
4. How do you plan
   to do Backup etc.

Do have look  at these article

1. https://habiletechnologies.com/blog/better-saving-files-database-file-system/
2. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150787